# ElasticSearch RestHighLevelClient provides inaccurate results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES with SpringBoot. I try to search results using the following code snippet.

```
  SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("businesses");
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "Microsoft"));
    SearchResponse response = highLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    SearchHit[] searchHit = response.getHits().getHits();
```

When I iterate through "searchHits", none of the names matches "Microsoft". It always returns some other names. Also, the list of other names is consistent evrytime. Is anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `name` field should be `keyword` in your document mapping. I guess you didn't set it explicitly and by default it is set to `text`.